# Qt 5.3.2 on i.MX6 using Yocto: problems with QML WebView

Tags: linux, qt, webview, qt5, yocto

I am trying to compile Qt 5.3.2 for i.MX6, using Yocto. I am using the `dizzy` branches of both `fsl-community-bsp` and `meta-qt5`.

The compilation succeeds, I compile `meta-toolchain-qt5` and I configure QtCreator... actually I am able to run minimal Qt applications (both widget-based and QML-based). My problem comes when I want to use the QML WebView element... In such a scenario the application crashes with various (random?) errors: `SIGILL`, `SIGABRT`, pointer exceptions and so on... as if someone is overwriting the code memory with garbage...

Here it the full stacktrace (taken from QtCreator):

[image: stacktrace]

My source code is very simple... my `main.cpp` is the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    view.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}
```

My `main.qml` is the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtWebKit 3.0

Rectangle {
    visible: true
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 480
    height: 272

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }

    WebView
    {
        id: webview
        width: 480
        height: 272
        url: "qrc:/test.html"
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }
}
```

`test.html` is a standard HTML page (only some sample text in it)...

If I remove `WebView` from my QML the application works fine... Any ideas about what is causing the problem? Does someone else has similar problems?

If it helps, please consider that using Yocto I have compiled the image named `fsl-image-multimedia-full` and all Yocto and `meta-qt5` files are unchanged, except for the fact that I made some modifications to avoid compiling Qt examples, to exclude xcb and dbus support and to include sqlite support.

Comment: You can see squat on that image. Too small for text to be readable.

Comment: @ddriver Sure you can -- right click, view image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a working solution... Playing with framebuffer settings, I've succeeded in making my test working passing `fbpix=BGR32` to the kernel command line...

My command line is now:

```
console=ttymxc3,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait rw video=mxcfb0:dev=lcd,SAMSUNG-LMS700,if=RGB24,fbpix=BGR32 splash consoleblank=0 video=mxcfb1:off video=mxcfb2:off
```

and it does work!